# FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE error Google-managed ssl certificate for hosting a static sub-domain website through Google Storage and Load Balancing

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage, cloudflare

I am trying to host a website on a subdomain e.g. `sub.example.com` through Google Bucket/Load Balancing with HTTPS traffic using Google-managed certificate.

I am using Cloudflare as DNS Server with **Full** end-to-end encryption enabled. The error I got in google console dasboard is [FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting?_ga=2.63188655.-1261873224.1585087860#domain-status) that Google interprets that like below:

> Certificate provisioning failed for the domain. Either of the following might be the issue:
>
> - The domain's DNS record doesn't resolve to the IP address of the    Google Cloud load balancer. To resolve this issue, update the DNS
>   records to point to the load balancer's IP address.
> - The SSL Certificate isn't attached to the load balancer's target     proxy. To resolve this issue, update the load balancer configuration.
>   Google Cloud continues to try to provision the certificate while the  managed status is PROVISIONING.

The AA record is added properly to Cloudflare DNS records and there is no problem in accessing `sub.example.com` when using HTTP for Load Balancing configuration.

Please consider that the `example.com` is SSL enabled using a self-signed Cloudflare certificate. Should these URLs (i.e. `example.com` and `sub.example.com`) use the same certificate? I assume not as Google LB is going to the server the requests on `sub.example.com`.

Any help to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, contact Google Cloud Support as we can help you further through a private channel. https://cloud.google.com/support-hub